# How to convert Kivy canvas to SVG?

Tags: python, svg, canvas, kivy

Suppose I drew several geometric shapes in kivy (see example below).
How can I convert them to a single svg file?

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout
    canvas:
        Color
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle
            size: 100,100
            pos: 100,100
        Ellipse
            size: 100,100
            pos: 300,100
        Triangle
            points: 500, 100, 500, 200, 600, 100
'''

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(KV))
```

Comment: We simply can't write all the code required to do so, but if you can find out a way to get the bounding boxes of all shapes, and convert them to [SVG format](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/), that should do the trick.

Comment: There is no prebuilt way to do this. However, if you wanted to, I don't think it would be that hard to write an svg exporter that extracts the canvas instructions and converts them to an svg format - at least, something that would work for the majority of cases.